# XML search for string XPath query talend

Tags: xml, xpath, etl, talend

I've try to use the tFileInputXML to extract a node from an xml. The xml structure I have is like the following extraction:

```
<catalog>
<article>
<id>10001</id>
<name>AAAAXXXXAAA</name>
<desc>LLLLLL</desc>
</article>
</catalog>
```

In the tFileInputXML I have the setup the parameters like below to find a particular product by id:

[image]

The problem is that my output is always 0 rows. Could you please give me some lights to check why is not working correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What node are you trying to retrieve ?

Comment: The article node filtered by ID, having in mind that the original xml file have more than 1 million of products.

Comment: try loop query as '/catelog/'

Comment: What do you mean article node ? It has child nodes, do you want those as well (article as xml) ? I see that you have an id column in your mapping..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but if you want the article node that has a certain id (as an xml), here's how to do it.

I have this xml as input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<catalog>
    <article>
        <id>10001</id>
        <name>AAAAXXXXAAA</name>
        <desc>LLLLLL</desc>
    </article>
    <article>
        <id>10002</id>
        <name>ZZZZZZZZZZ</name>
        <desc>description</desc>
    </article>
</catalog>
```

Here's how I get the article node with an id of 10002 (check `Get nodes` option to get the xml):

[image]

[image]

**Edit**

The above works fine if you are looking for a single node. If you want to search for more than one node, here's a solution (notice the loop XPath query is now `/catalog/article`):

[image]

You can also use this expression `self::node()[contains('10001 10002', descendant::id)]`

Comment: Great ! I'm happy to help :)

Comment: Maybe you know, is there a way to search in xml like contains("10002","10003")

Comment: you are a genius

Comment: hi again, due to performance issues I've switched the generation mode to fast and less memory consuming (SAX) however it looks like the query is not working. Even thought it works with the generation mode DOM4j do you know why?

Comment: Hi, actually only Dom4j allows the use of xpath expressions; if you want to use SAX, maybe you can better performance by reading all your nodes and filtering the id you want with a tFilterRow: https://imgur.com/a/s8xW6
Here I extract the article and its id, then I filter on the id I want.